# ImageJ: Get specific Radiobox

Tags: java, vector, imagej

I'm working on a Plugin for compressing images. Before the "magic happens" the user should decide, if he wants use a method with three or four neighbors. 
For this, I created a generic Dialog with a RadioButtonGroup.

This works fine, my question is how do I get the choice of the user? The Method getRadioButton gives a Vector back. But I don’t know how to handle this. My plan was to use the Index of the Button which was choose as a parameter for my main class, but I don’t see a way to manage this.

Have you any idea?

Edit: My Code (without import)

```
public class FrameDemo_ extends PlugInFrame {
    public FrameDemo_ (){
        super("FrameDemo");
    }

    public void run (String arg){
        String[] items = {"Option A", "Option B"};
        GenericDialog gd = new GenericDialog("FrameDemo settings");
        gd.addRadioButtonGroup("Test",items,2,1,"0");
        gd.showDialog();
        if (gd.wasCanceled()){
            IJ.error("PlugIn canceled!");
            return;
        }
        String input;
        Vector vec = gd.getRadioButtonGroups();
        Object obj = vec.elementAt(0);
        input = obj.toString();

        this.setSize(250, 250);
        this.add(new Label(input, Label.CENTER));
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

My Target is to do something like:

```
input = obj.Somefunction; // Input contains for exampe "A" for Option A

class RealPlugin (parameter input){
    if(input == A) { do something } // Pseudocode...not the real if for a string 

else if {input == B) {do something else }
```

My Problem is, when I convert the Object to String it is:

java.awt.CheckboxGroup[selectedCheckbox=java.awt.Checkbox[checkbox0,0,0,66x23,invalid,label=Option A,state=true}}

I'm sure there is a way for String manipulation, but I don't think this is the proper way to do this. I mean this must be a so typical job (use a radiobuttongroup to get a user choice) that there must be a clever way or a function...

Comment: Please show, what you have done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: questions like these are usually answered much faster on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/), where more ImageJ experts will read them.

---

To retrieve the result from a radio button group, use the `getNextRadioButton` method of [GenericDialog](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/index.html?ij/gui/GenericDialog.html). Here's a small Groovy script that can be run directly from the [script editor](http://imagej.net/Script_Editor) in ImageJ:

```groovy
import ij.gui.GenericDialog

gd = new GenericDialog("FrameDemo Settings")

items = ["Option A", "Option B"]
gd.addRadioButtonGroup("Test", (String[]) items, 2, 1, "0")

gd.showDialog()

if (gd.wasOKed()) {
    answer = gd.getNextRadioButton()
    println answer
}
```

---

With [**ImageJ2**](http://imagej.net/ImageJ2) (that comes included with the [Fiji](http://imagej.net/Fiji) distribution of ImageJ), it's much easier to get this kind of choice, using SciJava [script parameters](http://imagej.net/Script_Parameters):

```groovy
// @String(label="Choice", choices={"Option A", "Option B"}, style="radioButtonVertical") choice

println choice
```

In Java, the same would look like this:

```
@Plugin(type = Command.class, menuPath = "Plugins>My New Plugin")
public class MyNewPlugin implements Command {

    @Parameter (label="Choice", choices={"Option A", "Option B"}, style="radioButtonVertical") 
    private String choice;

    // your code here
}
```

For a full example, see https://github.com/imagej/example-imagej-command

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I tried to use your code snippets the last two days but all I get are error codes in the ide (IntelliJ) or the Message “Unable to load plugin (ins)”. 
I assumed my code should work in the place “your code here”, I do some changes on it to see if this helps, but all in all it won’t work.
I look at your example, but it doesn’t really help me.
Can you give me a simple example where, after a radio button choice, a new window with the message “A” for Option A an “B” for Option B as a String in center of the windows appears?